# Custom tikz shapes: High level alternative to \pgfdeclareshape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

So I've been researching making own shapes in TikZ. As most things in LaTeX, I've come to learn, it seems to have an extremely deep rabbit hole.

So I was wondering - is there an easy way out?

**Is it possible to define a new shape that can be used "between two coordinates" (i.e. `\draw (A) open box (B)`) in e.g. `\path` and `\draw`, which use familiar notation when defining?**

For example, one could do something like this;
As a minimal example I'm making a rectangle that has no top:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\tikzset{
  % When open box is called via edge, draw a rectangle with no top:
  open box/.code={%
      \pgfkeysalso{%
        to path={%
            let
            \p{start}=(\tikztostart),
            \p{end}=(\tikztotarget)
            in
            (\tikztostart) -| (\tikztotarget)
            (\x{start},\y{start}) -- (\x{start},\y{end})
            % Make a fitted node to get good anchors
            node[fit={(\tikztostart)(\tikztotarget)}, inner sep=0pt](#1){}
          }
      }
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) edge[open box={therect}] (2,2);
    % How can this be switched with e.g:            %<---
    % \draw (0,0) open box[name=therect] (2,2) %<---
    \node at (therect.center){RECT!};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I don't find this syntax half bad, actually, but I was wondering if there is something simpler that is made for this kind of thing, but I just haven't stumbled across?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how to achieve the syntax you are suggesting without changing the Ti*k*Z parser. The latter can be done but it is quite some effort. Explicit examples are given e.g. [in Jake's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34986/121799) and [in Loopspace's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35050/121799). However, the latter also contains a very explicit statement:

> **I still strongly recommend the to path solution. Do not subvert the TikZ code unless you know what you are doing.**

I do share the opinion expressed in this statement. Therefore I just suggest to shorten your code (no `calc` needed, nor `\pgfkeysalso`, the way the path is drawn here the corners look good, the node text can be the second argument).

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  % When open box is called via edge, draw a rectangle with no top:
  open box/.style 2 args={%
        to path={%
            (\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztostart) -| (\tikztotarget)
            node[fit={(\tikztostart)(\tikztotarget)}, inner sep=0pt](#1){#2}
          }
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[open box={therect}{RECT!}] (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also make it more Ti*k*Zy by using pgf keys instead of a style with multiple options.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  % When open box is called via edge, draw a rectangle with no top:
  open box/.style={%
        /utils/exec=\tikzset{/tikz/obox/.cd,#1},
        to path={%
            (\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztostart) -| (\tikztotarget)
            node[fit={(\tikztostart)(\tikztotarget)},obox/style]
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/obox/name})
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/obox/contents}}
          }
    },obox/.cd,name/.initial={},contents/.initial={},style/.style={inner sep=0pt}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[open box={name=rect,contents={RECT!}}] (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If the aim is just to create a node shape of this type, you could do e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[open box/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,
name=opbo,append after command={(opbo.north west)|-(opbo.south east)--(opbo.north east)}}]
\draw node[open box]{RECT!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah - just did the open rectangle for simplicity. Was thinking that neural network layers with neurons would be just a _tad_ too much :p But `style 2 args` is better, I agree :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Clearly I do not know what you have in mind but I also do not see why it is so cumbersome to write `to[open box=...]` instead of, say, `open box[...]`. Of course, if I knew what you really want to do then there may be a way without changing the parser. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241532/121799) what changing the parser may mean. You may also use pgf keys instead of many arguments.

Comment: Yeah. Doing `to[open box]` or `edge[open box]` is fine, really. Its' mostly out of curiosity :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman You can look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34986/121799) for an explicit example. Or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35050/121799). But I share LoopSpace's opinion: **I still strongly recommend the to path solution. Do not subvert the TikZ code unless you know what you are doing.**

Comment: @marmot I'm now curious as to whether anyone other than me has released a package on CTAN that subverts the TikZ parser.

Comment: @LoopSpace I do not know. However, there is a rather new (?) module `\usepgfmodule{parser}` that allows you to parse stuff. This can be used to translate stuff to styles that insert some paths, an explicit example can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481179/121799). (No, I do not know why one user wants to write three different answers to one question or downvote [an existing accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373/121799) just because one wants to add another answer, but my suspicion is that our site is a big experiment in sociology. ;-))